# Map values of JsonNode arrays in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have two JsonNode objects which are arrays returned from API calls and look like this

exportedNodeArray:

```
[
    {"key":"111", "value":"aaa"},
    {"key":"222", "value":"bbb"},
    {"key":"333", "value":"ccc"}
]
```

localNodeArray

```
[
    {"key":"999", "value":"aaa"},
    {"key":"888", "value":"bbb"},
    {"key":"777", "value":"ccc"}
]
```

The required output is a Map of any keys which correspond to the same values in each array.  The values are guaranteed to be unique within an array.

```
"111"="999"
"222"="888"
"333"="777"
```

This function returns the correct result, but seems like a very in-elegant way to do it.

```
fun mapIds(exportedNodeArray: JsonNode, localNodeArray: JsonNode) : MutableMap<String, String?> {
    val localMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    localNodeArray.forEach {
        localMap[it["value"].asText()] = it["key"].asText()
    }
    val idMap = mutableMapOf<String, String?>()
    exportedNodeArray.forEach {
        idMap[it["key"].asText()] = localMap[it["value"].asText()]
    }
    return idMap
}
```

I am new to Kotlin, and would like to understand a more functional approach.  Especially if there is a way to access elements of a JsonNode by attribute value, and accomplish this in a single loop or map call.

Answer (score 0):

If you define one more function, it could look like this:

```
fun mapIds(exportedNodeArray: JsonNode, localNodeArray: JsonNode) : Map<String, String> {
    val localConverted = convert(localNodeArray)
    return convert(exportedNodeArray)
        .filterKeys(localConverted::containsKey)
        .map { it.value to localConverted.getValue(it.key) }
        .toMap()
}

fun convert(node: JsonNode): Map<String, String> = node.associate {
    it["value"].asText() to it["key"].asText() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with the "associate" function, which works well in this case.  I changed the function body to be this:


`val localMap = localNodeArray.associate { it[“value”].asText() to it[“key”].asText() }`


`return exportedNodeArray.associate { it[“key”].asText() to localMap[it[“value”].asText()] }`